# How to call a function within an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def get_stdlib_packages():
    import sys
    import isort
    minor_version=sys.version_info[1]
    python_version='py'+'3'+str(minor_version)
    all_stdlib_packages_list=isort.stdlibs.python_version.stdlib
    return all_stdlib_packages_list
```

AttributeError: module 'isort.stdlibs' has no attribute 'python_version'

I've tried using str(python_version).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: use `getattr(isort.stdlibs, python_version).stdlib`